# Google Analytics: Goals Overview isn't working while Goal Flow is working

Tags: google-analytics

I've set Goals which generated non-zero value when I verified the goal with "Verify this goal" button.

"Goal Flow" is working fine.

However, all the other reports under "Goals" section other than Goal Flow, such as "Overview", "Goal URLs", etc., is not working, which means they show 0 goal completion.

If Goal Flow showed 0 goal completion as well, the problem would have been simpler, but it shows non-zero goal completions, actually 200 something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out that Goals section works properly only after a day passed. It tracks goal completion only after the goal has been set.